# Affiliate Links using GEM: rack-affiliates with localhost - not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If one could kindly help or advise me, i would be very grateful. I am trying to get the gem "rack-affiliates" to work but unfortunately it is not working and there is not enough help nor documentation out there.

- i have bundle installed the gem "`rack-affiliates`"
- i have created the table "`affiliates`" with the columns `name:string`, `tag:string`
- for the table "`users`" i have the columns `ref:string`, `affiliate_tag:string`, `affiliate_tag_ref:string`

the affiliate_tag is automatically produced when a user signups on the platform with the below method is the usr.rb file

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_create :generate_affiliate_tag

  def generate_affiliate_tag
    begin
      reference_length = 6
      self.affiliate_tag = "SPz_" + Devise.friendly_token.first(reference_length).tr('+/=-', '0aZ')
    end while self.class.exists?(affiliate_tag: affiliate_tag)
  end
end
```

- therefore example when `user_A` registers on the platform, user_A will receive an `affiliate_tag`: `SPz_bpQFGq`
- with this the user_A [affiliate user] will have the affiliate link: `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up?ref=SPz_bpQFGq`
- When `user_A` gives the affiliate link to `user_B`. After user_B has signuped, i would like the ref in the url `SPz_bpQFGq` to be stored under the column `affiliate_tag_ref:string` for user_B (under the users table)

i have done all that the [documentation](https://github.com/alexlevin/rack-affiliates) requested:

- bundle installed the gem "`rack-affiliates`"
- updated the file config/application.rb with the below code:
  [image]

but i am sure why it is not working. If i am doing ti all wrong, you advise and guidance will be much much appreciated.
Or if one could direct me to a better documentation on how to build affiliate links and track them successfully i would be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Affiliates, { :param => 'ref', :domain => 'localhost', :path => "/" }
```

instead of

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Affiliates, { :param => 'ref', :domain => '.localhost', :path => "/" }
```